# How can I deploy firebase functions through github actions?

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions, github-actions, firebase-cli

In my project, which has a folder structure as shown here:

```
dev-internal-web
-.firebase
-.github
-e2e
-functions
-node_modules
-src
(misc files)
```

I have a functions folder, which houses firebase functions. I'm looking to automate deployment of that through my actions script as shown below:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master

jobs:
  hosting-deploy:
    name: Deploy Hosting
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    - uses: actions/setup-node@master
      with:
        node-version: '10.x'
    - run: npm install
    - run: npm run build
    - uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
      with:
        args: deploy --only hosting --project=tombstone-roleplay
      env:
        FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}

  functions-deploy:
      name: Deploy Functions
      runs-on: ubuntu-latest

      steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - uses: chrissank/deploy-firebase-functions@1.0.0
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          TARGET: default
```

The actions for the firebase hosting on the Angular project inside the folder works fine, but the second script fails with the following error:

```
=== Deploying to 'tombstone-roleplay'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /github/workspace/functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

sh: 1: tslint: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2020-10-04T14_06_06_215Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

After following the instructions in the comment to remove tslint and update my script to what can be found in this article: https://medium.com/mainlycoding-com/automate-firebase-functions-deployment-with-github-actions-ci-a0eb10fa308d, I received the following error:

```
=== Deploying to 'project-name'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint /github/workspace/functions
> tslint --project tsconfig.json

sh: 1: tslint: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! functions@ lint: `tslint --project tsconfig.json`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2020-10-04T14_06_06_215Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

What am I doing wrong in the "functions-deploy" section?

Comment: I found a link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint There is a red message there that can help: This package has been deprecated
Author message:

TSLint has been deprecated in favor of ESLint. Please see https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/4534 for more information.

Comment: @MrTech after trying to remove the tslint (I just re-init'd firebase functions since I hadn't done any work there yet) I now am getting this error: `npm ERR! functions@ build: tsc`

Comment: To move this along, I've found a detailed tutorial that can help you. https://medium.com/mainlycoding-com/automate-firebase-functions-deployment-with-github-actions-ci-a0eb10fa308d

Comment: @MrTech I've given that a go and it's not working for me. I tried adding it to the end of my original file, and that didn't work, so I tried a new file (which didn't work either). The hosting has no problems but I copied the script at the bottom of that article and it doesn't work.

Comment: To look into this further, were there any error messages when it did not work?

Comment: I've updated the post to include the second error.

Comment: I've found the error message link https://npm.community/t/elifecycle-npm-run-script-build/4722 and it seems like a memory issue (ELIFECYCLE).

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd go about doing anything about that since it's GitHub actions; not my own PC.

Comment: To uncover more detail, can you please provide /github/home/.npm/_logs/2020-10-04T14_06_06_215Z-debug.log

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to that file since it's in GitHub actions. I'll look into if I'm able to find a way to access it, but I don't think there is a way to.

Answer (score 0):

The `deploy` step is different to the `build` step (different folders), so you need to run `npm install` again or bring over the deploy `node_module` dependencies with your build artifact.

Here is my `firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ install",
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run lint",
      "npm --prefix ./functions/ run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

There is some discussion over here:
https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/30

Also, ensure `tslint`, `eslint`, and `tsc` are in your `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file.